# Is there any way to convert PrintWriter into ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, servlets

I want to convert PrintWriter object into ByteArrayOutputStream. and this I am displaying as a PDF.

Comment: Not enough information. Do you *create* the `PrintWriter`? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are using PrintWriter exactly (please post your code), but instead of converting objects you can write lines directly to `ByteArrayOutputStream` like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(byteStream);
pw.write("example");
pw.flush();
```

or (flush after closing `PrintWriter`):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(byteStream);
pw.write("example");
pw.close();
```

or (auto-flushable):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(byteStream, true);
pw.println("example");
```

Let me know whether you prefer other solution and add some more details then(your code).